# Appropriate adjective for 'feature set'

Tags: adjectives, software, it-its-itself

Let's say I am comparing two software products. And one of them offers more features (functionality). What adjective would you use to describe the size of their feature sets?

> First program has larger/broader/wider feature set.
>
> Second program has smaller/narrower feature set.

Are these correct? Or would you write something else?

Edit: This is for an internal document for the sales department (so I would say it should use "marketing language"). It's the comparison of two software products, the one with more features is supposed to be better.

Thanks

Comment: What did your dictionaries and search engines leave unclear about that, please, rluks?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin which dictionaries or resources would you recommend when looking for a reference (in this case)? I usually use collocation dictionary at freecollocation.com

Comment: Again, context is king. Are you marketing the narrower feature set as something positive?  Is this just an explanation for the larger feature set being more expensive? Or is this a product comparison between two different vendors?

Comment: It's the latter. Comparison of two products, the one with more features is supposed to be better. This is for an internal document for the sales department (so I would say it should use "marketing language").

Answer (score 1):

First program is more feature-rich.

*A system is said to be feature-rich when it has many options and functional capabilities available to the user.*

> source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_feature

Answer (score 1):

*larger* and *smaller* are the least semantically loaded.  Since few people are unopinionated about the value of a larger or smaller feature set in most contexts, it's important to decide whether you want to communicate your opinion, be neutral or even mitigate the possible bias of the audience.

Broadly positive for larger: *broad, full, rich, comprehensive*

Ambiguous for larger: *packed*

Negaive for larger: *baroque, overloaded*

Broadly positive for small: *lean, minimalist, austere*

Mostly negative for smaller: *narrow, meagre*